# What are some good DirectX resources for a beginner?

Tags: c++, resources, directx

I'm learning DirectX as part of a hobby project. I've been looking for some good online resources for DirectX9 (using C++, if that distinction matters), but haven't found anything that's a) great for a beginner and b) up to date.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I started using DirectX I found this to be the best resource around for basic stuff:
http://www.directxtutorial.com/

When you start reaching an intermediate level they want you to pay a subscription but all the good basic stuff is free. Tutorials are clear and literally step-by-step.

This is website is not bad at all either: http://www.toymaker.info/ - with some good project downloads.

If you have problems the best place to go in my experience is http://www.gamedev.net/ , they have great articles and forums with plenty of so-called gurus.

Comment: Great answer. Don't forget that MSDN is a great reference for when you're reading the beginner tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

- [Toymaker](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/index.html)
- [Triple Buffer](http://triplebuffer.devmaster.net/list.php?display=s&page=0)
- [DirectX4VB](http://directx4vb.vbgamer.com/DirectX4VB/TUT_DX9Start.asp)
- [32Bits](http://www.32bits.co.uk/)

[Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556229135): Not an online resource, but that book was very helpful to me.

There's also the DirecX SDK documentation, which should be your definitive resource.

Answer (score 1):

Gamedev.net is probably a good place to look

Answer (score 0):

[CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/)